# Could not find com.facebook.react:react-android

Tags: react-native, react-android

I'm trying to update the sdk of an app in react native and I'm running into a lot of problems. The last one is this and I don't know what to do:

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

> Could not find com.facebook.react:react-android:.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :react-native-reanimated
> Could not find com.facebook.react:hermes-android:.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :react-native-reanimated

My info:

```
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19044
    CPU: (6) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8400 CPU @ 2.80GHz
    Memory: 18.33 GB / 31.87 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.13.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 6.14.8 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    Watchman: Not Found
  SDKs:
    Android SDK: Not Found
    Windows SDK:
      AllowAllTrustedApps: Disabled
      AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense: Enabled
      Versions: 10.0.18362.0, 10.0.19041.0, 10.0.22000.0
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: AI-221.6008.13.2211.9619390
    Visual Studio: 17.4.33213.308 (Visual Studio Community 2022), 16.11.32106.194 (Visual Studio Community 2019)
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.12 - C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin\javac.EXE
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: ^16.14.0 => 16.14.0
    react-native: ^0.71.6 => 0.71.6
    react-native-windows: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.1"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.2")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com/"}
        
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        
    }
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: what is the SDK?  Have you looked on their github issues page to see if anyone else is having the same problem?

Comment: The last one and yes but I can't find any issue